# Group coordination for a siyum

Tags: tzibur-community, time, yahrtzeit, siyum

My understanding is that a [*siyum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siyum) should be made on the last bit of the text being studied. Thus, if the entire [*Mishna*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah) (all six "orders") is studied for someone's [yahrzeit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahrzeit), the last *mishna* (individual piece of the *Mishna*) to be studied should be the one studied as the *siyum*.

It often occurs that many people band together to complete the *Mishna* before someone's first yahrzeit. There's a sign-up sheet, which says something along the lines of "Please complete your portion by [the yahrzeit]". And on the yahrzeit, someone completes the last bit at a meal.

But that meal is not always in the last minute of the day. So those finishing "by [the yahrzeit]" may not have finished their respective portion. How, then, does the one who's completing the last bit know that everyone's done by that time?

- Does he not, and take his chances?
- Does he hold the *siyum after* the yahrzeit?
- Do those studying understand, generally, that they should finish *before* (and not on) the yahrzeit? (I haven't understood that!)
- Does he call all those studying to see whether they've finished their respective portions and, if not, ask them to do so before *x* o'clock on the yahrzeit when the *siyum* will be made?
- Or what?

Any sources, experience, anecdotes, etc. will be appreciated.

Comment: FYI an online signup sheet: http://hadranalach.com/

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68640

Answer (score 8):

In my experience. . .

- Generally, yes, and many knowledgeable people I've met who have a lot of *siyumim* under their belts don't seem to mind *that* much about it (which I have always found surprising).
- Usually not. Indeed things relating to anniversaries generally ignore the time of day and rather calculate the reocurrence of the original date's *day* as their target.
- Definitely not.
- "Call" in the more general sense of "contact", and not necessarily on the day, but at some prior date to ensure they are all on pace to finish on time. I have observed that a polite way to ensure people are aware of their expected finishing date (and even time) is to invite them to the *siyum*.

These are my impressions and observations.

---

I thought [the question to which this is the answer] was your question at first, and it is still relevant to *siyum*-timing, so I'm throwing it in. The [*Mahara"m Mintz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Isaac_ha-Levi_Minz) wrote (in the middle [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2355)) that

> כשבאים לסוף מסכתא ישייר מעט בסוף עד שעת הכושר, יומא דראוי לתקן בו סעודה וכו'. כמו שנוהגים לשייר מעט עד ערב פסח לסיום בעד הבכורים שלא יתענו.
>
> When one nears the end of a *masechta* he may (should?) leave off a little bit at the end until an opportune time, a day which calls for throwing a festive meal etc. Like how we tend to leave off a little bit until *erev Pesach* for a *siyum* benefiting first-borns so that they need not fast.

I did not find this on my own. It - along with a bunch of interesting ramifications - is mentioned in [this *shi'ur*](http://traffic.libsyn.com/kmtt/sheelot_teshuvot_eng_10_5771_Tabory.mp3) by Rav Binyamin Tabory.