# If one or more women complete a Talmudic tractate, can they make a siyum?

Tags: halacha, women, minyan, siyum

There is this [related M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31818/5275) about women joining a men's siyum.

If one or more women complete a Talmudic tractate can / should they make a siyum? I know that women cannot form a minyan, however, everal related questions to the siyum activities:

- Can a woman say the *hadran* and following paragraphs without a minyan, or should she have a man say it?
- You would need a minyan (10 men) to say the *Kaddish* at the end. If you have that, can / should the woman say the Kaddish? If not, why would that be a different rule than a woman saying the Mourner's Kaddish in a minyan?
- If you do have a minyan, can the woman recite the ending Mishnah to make the siyum, or should a man do it? Can a man do it if he did not complete or read part of the tractate?
- Considering that if there is a minyan (esp. for Kaddish) that means that there isa mixed crowd, must there be a mechitza (partition) during the recital of the last Mishnah, the *hadran* and / or the Kaddish?

Comment: Why couldn't she say the hadran?

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31818/5514

Answer (score 2):

Harav Beari addresses this question [here:](http://www.din.org.il/2012/02/20/%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA/)
He asks firstly whether it is dependent on the obligation to learn Torah, which is primarily a Mitzva for men (as opposed to children), etc.
He quotes the 'Tzafnad Pa'aneach' who explains why children can make a Siyum, before questioning whether there may be a difference (as children may have more of an obligation).
He quotes 'Shut Minchas Dovid 5-99' who writes that wome don't make a Siyum on completing the Torah, though writes that if one learned something that would help her in her Mitzva observance, then she should make a Siyum on that.

Unfortunately, he doesn't address whether the woman says Kaddish and your other questions.

Comment: Who is Rabbi beari?

Comment: @Mefaresh, I have no idea, but anyone who finds, understands and quotes the Tzafnad Pa'aneach has to be able to do some serious research.

Comment: "if one learned something that would help her in her Mitzva observance, then she should make a Siyum on that" which is most masechtos.  Almost all halachos apply to men and women equally.

Answer (score 2):

In the podcast [Daf Yomi for Women](https://main.hadran.org.il/) (soon to be renamed Hadran Daf Yomi for Women), the speaker, Michelle Cohen Farber, does say Hadran at the conclusion of masechtot.  She doesn't have a man say it for her and the women who learned with and from her.  She does not, as far as I recall, say kaddish because there is presumably not a minyan of men present.

A mechitza is required only for a service containing shmona esrei (shacharit, mincha, maariv, musaf or neila) that meets regularly.  An occasional minyan (such as at a wedding for example) does not require a mechitza but only that men & women stand/sit separately rather than mixed.  Similarly, a service that doesn't include shmona esrei, such as the wedding itself (the "chuppah" as event) requires that people be seperate, but not a mechitza per se.  So a siyum wouldn't require a mechitza.

Comment: Is no mechitza needed for a regular slichot service?

Comment: @DoubleAA what makes you think a mechitza would be required for selichot? Often there is one because it is in a shul that has one anyway.

Comment: It's a pretty formal shul gathering prayer type thing. If you want to exempt it from a mechitza I'd think the onus is clearly on you. What makes you think shmona esrei specifically is the obligating factor?