# looking for resources on making a group siyum of talmud bavli

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, talmud-bavli, siyum

I would like to organize a group siyum of talmud bavli (for a refuah shelema). Does anyone know of downloadable signup sheets, or the like, that I can use, that split up the talmud, say, 25 dapim at a time or whatever (for about 100 people)?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9409/group-coordination-for-a-siyum#comment74107_9409