# Is one able to make two siyums in two different places

Tags: halacha, tzibur-community, mishna, siyum

We have divided the 60 mishnayot of shas for a rebbis yahrzeit among talmidim on two continents.
Let us say thirty on each. Since they all cannot attend one siyum can one make two. Although by the time the later one makes, there already has been a siyum on what they have learned by those attending the first siyum on another continent. Or since they have not attended  can they make their own siyum.
The question will really apply to times when a siyum allows you to eat like a firstborn on erev pesach.
Or let us make the question a bit harder. It has been divided in such a way that no one has learned a whole mesechta. 
So unless one is allowed to make a siyum a second time they will not be able to make it even on one mesechta.

Comment: No one meaning no group? Or no single individual? The latter is less of a problem than the former... If 30 or 300 people intentionally divide Seder zerayim, why can't they have a collective siyum?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9409

Comment: Isaac Not sure what you mean. I wrote that they are on two continents and cant all partake in only one. The yahrzeit is on shabbos as well.

Comment: The question can also be added if one can learn one gemoro for two siyums or must one learn it twice.

Comment: If I am learning G'mara with a Chavrusa and we leave 3 or 4 lines and then make separate siyumim or whatever the word would be. Why not?

Comment: @CashCow If you both learn the same gemoro that is ok to make two siyumim because the gemoro has be learned twice.