# Proper day and time for a Shloshim Seuda

Tags: minhag, time, mourning-aveilus, meal-seudah

Per [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371240/jewish/The-Shloshim.htm): "Traditionally, families gather on the eve of the Shloshim to share support, recite prayers and Psalms, and to give charity in the merit of the deceased. Many will also make a Siyum, celebrating the completion of the Mishnayot studied to merit the soul of the deceased, as well as a meal."

When is the proper day and time for a Shloshim Seuda?  Are there differing minhagim in this regard?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9409

Comment: What is the makor (source) for all of this anyway?

Comment: Yes there certainly are different minhagim. There are some who are makpid do it after nightfall.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search on this topic came up with no consistent information regarding what time of day one should make this se'udah. It is not universal custom to do one at all on the day of shloshim.

I noticed one link from the Mirrer yeshiva stating a seudah done at night midweek. [Dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2013/12/04/customs-of-the-shloshim/) answered a related reader question about doing this on Friday, and the answer was that of Friday is inconvenient, it may be done Motza'ei Shabbat, meaning, at nighttime. Note that he says, "can", meaning that it could be done during the day, as well. BTW, it could, of course, be done on Shabbat, itself, which is what I have seen many do, though it's not specifically on the day of Shloshim, itself.

Answer (score 0):

There must be different options for such a *shloshim seuda*. In Israel, I have seen this happen towards the end of the afternoon of the 30th day ([from the day of burial](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281615/jewish/Shloshim-Observances.htm), which counts as first day), with a meal, *divrei* Torah and then praying *minha* together.

I recently asked a rav on behalf of someone who confirmed this was one of the minhagim in Israel.