# Time limit on making a Siyum

Tags: siyum

Suppose one learned a complete Mesechta and is just about ready to make a Siyum. Is there a time limit as to when he should make the Siyum? Can he wait 3 months to complete the last few lines?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/making-a-siyum-on-a-mesechta

Comment: Haven't we all learned the last few lines of most masechtot already anyway?

Comment: @DoubleAA, depends on the masechta, depends on the person.  If there are people regularly making siyumim somewhere you frequent, then yes, perhaps.  But if asked "What is the end of Masechet Ploni?" there are fairly few values of ploni for which I have a ready answer.

Comment: The "siyum" seems to be merely the celebration which if you haven't done yet, could be done at any point in honor and celebration of completely a part of the Torah. Even if you read off the lines already before. I finished learning mesectas Niddah already more than a month ago and didn't read the last few lines -- even though I obviously know what they say...The "siyum" was not made yet as I pushed it off in light of Purim and Pesach...Waiting for a good time (won't do it during the 9 days though...)

Comment: @Ploni done ! [    ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only sources I found on this come courtesy of [chaburas.org](http://www.chaburas.org/siyum.html) and say one can wait a bit but not a lot.

> Maharam Mintz claims that when one reaches the end of a tractate, he
>   should delay learning the end until an appropriate time comes for
>   making a siyum. Minchat Yitzchak (2:93) qualifies this by
>   distinguishing between waiting a little and waiting a lot. **One who
>   finishes a tractate the week before Pesach may draw out his learning a
>   bit so as to make a siyum on Erev Pesach, but one who finishes in
>   December should not save the last page for the four months until he
>   needs it to avoid having to fast.** He says that in such a case, one's
>   siyum would not be made out of simcha, but rather out of a desire to
>   satisfy one's physical needs.

Regarding a siyum during the nine days specifically see [here](http://www.congkins.org/nine-days-in-halacha.html)

> However, those who complete a significant portion of learning (e.g. a
>   tractate of Talmud) during the nine days solely for the purpose to eat
>   meat are not universally praised. In fact, the Aruch HaShulchan, while
>   allowing such behavior (suggesting that at least in this way, people
>   will learn Torah) does limit the people participating in this meal to
>   just Torah scholars associated with this learning project [Aruch
>   HaShulchan Orech Chaim 551:28].
>
> Nevertheless, the Mishna Berura, among
>   others does allow broader participation in the meal, extending it to
>   all those who would normally be invited to such a celebration [Mishna
>   Berura 551:75].   Once the week of Tisha B'Av begins (from the Sunday
>   before Tisha B'Av), the number of participants at such a siyum should
>   be limited to a minyan aside from the relatives of the person making
>   the siyum and those who are helping with them meal [Orach Chaim
>   551:10; Mishna Berura, ibid. note 77].