# Can one make a siyum if he finished learning the tractate already?

Tags: halacha, siyum

If one finished learning a tractate but did not make an official siyum with kadish, etc. can he still do this?

if yes, at what point is this too late?

Edit:  The question [Time limit on making a Siyum](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48951/time-limit-on-making-a-siyum?lq=1) is asking if one left the last few lines for the siyum. This question asks if one had learned the whole tractate.

Comment: Kaddish isn't part of a Siyum. It just ehappens to be said at public teaching of Torah, which people often do at a Siyum.

Comment: @DoubleAA isnt there a special kaddish for siyum.

Comment: No. Some people (not all) use the same Kaddish as at a burial at a Siyum where there is a Minyan and Torah study because they do Siyumim on Yahrtzeits. No one ever enacted special liturgy for a Siyum. What's commonly said is just the regular prayer for after study, which many say daily.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1354