# Keeping the last part of a learnt text for a siyum

Tags: siyum

There is a widespread custom, discussed in a few places on Mi Yodeya (such as [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9409/group-coordination-for-a-siyum/9415#9415)), to keep the last part of a masekhta unread in advance of the siyum. So, for example, if a person has just learnt Pesachim, they might wish to leave the final part of the final sugya unrevised, then learn it in the company of those who are joining them for the seudah. So far as I understand it, this is a *custom* only, and does not preclude reciting the hadran or the kaddish, and certainly not eating the meal.

My question concerns those who wish to observe this custom, but who are making a siyum in the morning, having just finished either Berakhot, Nazir, Yevamot or Kareitot. All four of those masekhtas conclude with the same brief sugya, which is also included at the conclusion of the davening:

אמר רבי אלעזר אמר רבי חנינא תלמידי חכמים מרבים שלום בעולם שנאמר וכל בניך למודי ה׳ ורב שלום בניך אל תקרי בניך אלא בוניך שלום רב לאוהבי תורתך ואין למו מכשול יהי שלום בחילך שלוה בארמנותיך למען אחי ורעי אדברה נא שלום בך למען בית ה׳ אלהינו אבקשה טוב לך ה׳ עוז לעמו יתן ה׳ יברך את עמו בשלום

Granted, this is only a custom, and granted that there is nothing problematic about omitting this part from one's davening anyway. My question is really about whether one might recite it in their davening and still be observing the minhag of keeping the last part of the masekhta unrevised. Is davening sufficiently distinct from learning as to permit this possibility? Or should one who wishes to observe this minhag be careful not to recite this section in any of their tefillot between completing the masekhta and having the siyum?

Comment: You may wish to see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1600, though it doesn't cite sources.

Comment: the sugia has an independent existence.  she is called at the end of each masechta.  But she is the  same object which must to be recited for the needs of the 4. Source.  common sense.

Comment: If they read it the day before haven't they still completed the whole tractate?

Comment: `in their davening and still be observing the minhag of keeping the last part of the masekhta unrevised` I am not sure that this is theoretically answerable. One can ask whether an obligation has been fulfilled. I don't think we can objectively determine whether a social practice is considered fulfilled. Considered by whom?

Comment: If one wanted to give a "detailed" siyum, wouldn't it be smart to perpare what he would say by reviewing the material before the actual siyum, itself? Technically, then, what would be wrong with doing personal "chazara" as part of the siyum?

Comment: @kouty - I don't understand what you're saying... "She is called at the end of each masechta. But she is the same object which must to be recited for the needs of the 4"? My apologies, but can you please rephrase?

Comment: each masechta did refer to the memra/berayta number xyz. each refers to the same,  to  what masechet a,  b,  c,  d referred?  to berayta number  xyz. and here is  it "bla bla bla..."

Comment: I'm sorry, @kouty, I still don't understand what you're talking about. Every masekhta refers to this baraita? Every masekhta refers to *some* baraita? Every masekhta concludes with a baraita?? And what do you mean by suggesting that it's a numbered baraita? What does that even mean, for a baraita to be numbered?

Comment: It's probably worth wondering if that section isn't an original part of those tractates but was added to facilitate Kaddish Derabanan being recited after their study.

Comment: @Shimon bM  perhaps I am wrong. It is not important

Comment: @DoubleAA - that's a really interesting idea! There are certainly some mishnayot that are liturgical in nature, but it never crossed my mind that any the gemara could be (notwithstanding the usage of certain sugyot in davening).

Comment: It's also at the end of Tamid, though without the collection of Pesukim recited after (beginning with Shalom Rav).